# I've written a code in VBA for an invoice. Problemo: No Increase in invoice number when opening.

Tags: vba, excel

```
 Private Sub CreateInvoice_Click()
```

1. This here is to empty all the cells of the invoice which needs to be filled out.

```
 Range("B10").Value = TextBox1.Text
 Range("B11").Value = TextBox2.Text
 Range("B12").Value = TextBox3.Text
 Range("A15").Value = TextBox4.Text
 Range("E15").Value = TextBox5.Text
 Range("I15").Value = TextBox6.Text
 Range("G15").Value = TextBox7.Text
 Range("D20").Value = TextBox8.Text
 Range("C20").Value = TextBox9.Text
 Range("H20").Value = TextBox10.Text
 Range("C32").Value = TextBox11.Text
 Range("I32").Value = TextBox12.Text
 Range("I40").Value = TextBox13.Text
 Range("J7") = Date


Dim reply As String
reply = "yes"
Dim row As Long
row = 21

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Invoices\"
Dim mydate As String
mydate = Date
mydate = Format(mydate, "dd_mm_yyyy")

Do While reply = "yes" Or reply = "y"
reply = InputBox("Do you wish to add another item to the invoice? yes/y for 
yes and no/n for no", "Add more items?")
If reply = "no" Or reply = "n" Then
```

2. Here is the saving code (I'm not sure if it's correct cause I'm new at this, but what I assume is that the micro-enabled excel which is the default excel which I input data into, doesn't save the invoice number when exiting) I've tried to put "ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True" here but still doesn't work.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & Range("J8").Value & "-" & mydate,
FileFormat:=51
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Else
QTY = InputBox("Please enter the quantity of next item ya habeeb.", "Enter
Quantity")
Cells(row, 3) = QTY
ItemName = InputBox("Please Enter the Name of this item habeeb", "Enter Item
Name")
Cells(row, 4) = ItemName
ItemPrice = InputBox("Please Enter the price of the item.", "Enter Item 
Price")
Cells(row, 8) = ItemPrice
ServiceDescription = InputBox("Please enter the next service
description.", "Enter Service Description")
Cells(33, 3) = ServiceDescription
ServicePrice = InputBox("Please Enter the service price habeeb", "Enter 
Service Price")
Cells(33, 9) = ServicePrice

End If
row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Where in your code that relates to the Invoice Number?

Comment: can you confirm that you put `FileFormat:=51` on the next line in your code? or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: yes I put it.. as an extension shortcut for "Microsoft Excel Worksheet"..

Comment: The following code was also entered in the "Thisworkbook" section and the invoice number is Cell (J8)

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
(    Range("J8").Value = Range("J8").Value + 1    )
Invoice.Show
End Sub

Comment: @PatricK previous comment

Comment: @DragonSamu Question Answered

Comment: Are you getting an error from your the Workbook_Open()?

Comment: no, I'm getting no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you continue your code on the next line you need to do the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & Range("J8").Value & "-" & mydate _
FileFormat:=51
```

Your actual problem is however that you `.SaveAs` your main workbook thus your main workbook is never saved but only the Invoice workbook.

My advice would be to always make a `.Copy` of the `Sheet` you want (if multiple copy them all over) to a new `Workbook` and `.Save` that `Workbook`.

Code example:

```
dim wb as Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks("name here.xlsm")
wb.Worksheets("Name Here").Copy
Activeworkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & Range("J8").Value & "-" & mydate _
FileFormat:=51
'Close Invoice wb
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Close main wb
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. The code example you gave solved the problem. Hope you have a great day..